# display sku infront of error message

Tags: php, extensions

we are using extension to upload the products 
we are using the following code to display the error message :
"sku already exists" ,
for ex, if sku is "sku001" we are getting message :
Skip import row, sku "sku001" already exist

```
    if(trim($value) == '') 
    {
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "sku"',$value);
    } 
    else 

        { 
        $existProductId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku(trim($value));
        if($existProductId)
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, sku "%s" already exist',$value);
        else
        $data[$code] = $value;
        }
        break;
```

in the same way when we upload the product with wrong attribute value.
we are getting message as : "Skip import row, is not valid value " for field "nike" [nike is attribute value ] , here in this message, we need to add the "sku" also . this is the code we are using for displaying attribute value error message

```
if($errorFlag && $validationRequiredFlag)
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"',$attributeValue,$attributeCode);
} 
else
{
if($validationRequiredFlag)
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist',$attributeCode);
}
}
return array($data, $errors);
}
```

please help me to display the "sku" infront of error message as like :

'S001: Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "nike"'

i am trying the following code :

```
if($errorFlag && $validationRequiredFlag && trim($value) == '')
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"',$value,$attributeValue,$attributeCode);
} 
else
{
$existProductId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku(trim($value));
if($validationRequiredFlag)
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist',$sku,$attributeCode);
else
$data[$code] = $value;
}
}
return array($data, $errors);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add %s

```
 $errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('%s : Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist',trim($value),$attributeCode);
```

Comment: now we are getting "attribute code" , but not the "sku"

Comment: check the sku value is it empty or display something?

Comment: this is we are getting : " : Skip import row, attribute "attribute code" does not exist"

Comment: %s is not working, is we have to replace something else with %S?

Comment: did you check the sku value is it there it is simple showing the sku value are not there

Comment: no , sku value is not displaying in output screen, it is present in excel sheet

Comment: update answer follow and tell what you get?

Comment: same output ,no changes...

Comment: echo the $value and put exit after it and check this value you getting or not?

Comment: i hide the $error line and 

iused this code : echo $value;

product imported

Comment: is it showing value?

Comment: when i used this code :



$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('%s :Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"',$value,$attributeValue,$attributeCode);

echo $value;

exit("Unable to connect to $site");


its keep on loading

Comment: i hide the echo statement i used this value : "echo $value;" product uploaded, it did't shoed the sku value

Comment: $errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__($value.': Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"',$attributeValue,$attributeCode);   try that

Comment: same output, sku is not displaying

Comment: attribute code are displaying?

Comment: yes, attribute code ,attribute value is displaying.

Comment: then the sku value are not there

Comment: no, thats why i am struggling

Comment: i mean if value are not there how you will display it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30245/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-2-and-qaisar-satti).